# How can I use a custom function with FILTER?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a custom function defined that extracts part of an address from a string:

```
/*
 * Return the number preceding 'N' in an address
 *    '445 N 400 E' => '445'
 *    '1083 E 500 N' => '500'
 */
function NorthAddress(address) {
  if (!address) return null;
  else {
    var North = new RegExp('([0-9]+)[\\s]+N');
    var match = address.match(North);
    if (match && match.length >= 2) {
      return match[1];
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

I want to use this function as one of the conditions in a call to `FILTER(...)` in the spreadsheet where I have these addresses stored:

```
=FILTER('Sheet 1'!A:A, NorthAddress('Sheet 1'!B:B) >= 450))
```

But when I call `NorthAddress` like this, it gets an array of all the values in column B and I can't for the life of me find any documentation as to how I need to handle that. The most obvious way (to me) doesn't seem to work: iterate over the array calling `NorthAddress` on each value, and return an array of the results.

What does my function need to return for `FILTER` to work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a custom function is called passing a multi-cell range, it receives a matrix of values (2d array), it's doesn't matter if the range is a single column or a single row, it's always a matrix. And you should return a matrix as well.

Anyway, I would not use a custom function to this, as there is already the native spreadsheet formulas: `RegexMatch`, `RegexExtract` and `RegexReplace` formulas. To get the "if match" behavior, just wrap them in a `IfError` formula.

Comment: Eg: `=FILTER('Sheet 1'!A:A;VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT('Sheet 1'!B:B;"([0-9]+) N"))>=450)`

Comment: Thanks for the extra mile AdamL :)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because address is, if you pass only one cell as arg a string, a range, a matrix of string.

So you return a string, FILTER use a boolean array to filter data, so the condition of your filter is `string` < `number`.

You just have to convert the string to a number when you returning a value

```
/*
 * Return the number preceding 'N' in an address
 *    '445 N 400 E' => '445'
 *    '1083 E 500 N' => '500'
 */
function NorthAddress(address) {
  if(typeof address == "string"){
    if (!address) return "#N/A";
    else {
      var North = new RegExp('([0-9]+)[\\s]+N');
      var match = address.match(North);
      if (match && match.length >= 2) {
        return parseInt(match[1]);
      }
      return "#N/A";
    }
  } else {
    var matrix = new Array();
    for(var i = 0; i<address.length; i++){
      matrix[i] = new Array();
      for(var j = 0; j<address[i].length; j++){
        var North = new RegExp('([0-9]+)[\\s]+N');
        var match = address[i][j].match(North);
        if (match && match.length >= 2) {
          matrix[i].push(parseInt(match[1]));
        }
      }
    }
    return matrix;
  }
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I will add this as an answer, because I found the custom function returns an error if numerical values are passed in the referenced cell or range when `toString()` is not invoked:

```
function NorthAddress(address) {
  if (!address) return null;
  else {
    if (address.constructor == Array) {
      var result = address;
    }
    else {
      var result = [[address]];
    }
    var north = new RegExp('([0-9]+)[\\s]+N');
    var match;
    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < result[0].length; j++) {
        match = result[i][j].toString().match(north);
        if (match && match.length >= 2) {
          result[i][j] = parseInt(match[1]);
        }
        else {
          result[i][j] = null;
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```